# Limited float precision and infinitely harmonic signal generation problem

Tags: c++, floating-point, trigonometry

Suppose we need to generate a very long harmonic signal, ideally infinitely long. At first glance, the solution seems trivial:

**Sample1:**

```
   float t = 0;
   while (runned)
   {
      float v = sinf(w * t);
      t += dt;
   }
```

Unfortunately, this is a non-working solution. For `t  >> dt` due to limited float precision incorrect values will be obtained. Fortunately we can call to mind that `sin(2*PI* n + x) = sin(x)` where n - arbitrary integer value, therefore modifying the example is not difficult to get an "infinite" analog

**Sample2:**

```
   float t = 0;
   float tau = 2 * M_PI / w;
   while (runned)
   {
      float v = sinf(w * t);
      t += dt;
      if (t > tau) t -= tau;
   }
```

For one physical simulation, I needed to get an infinite signal, which is the **sum of harmonic signals**, like that:

**Sample3:**

```
   float getSignal(float x)
   {
      float ret = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < modNum; i++)
         ret += sin(w[i] * x);
      return ret;
   }

   float t = 0;
   while (runned)
   {
      float v = getSignal(t);
      t += dt;
   }
```

In this form, the code does not work correctly for large `t`, for similar reasons for the Sample1. The question is - how to get an "infinite" implementation of the Sample3 algorithm? I assume that the solution should looks like an Sample2. A very important note - generally speaking, **w[i] is arbitrary and not harmonics**, that is, all frequencies are not multiples of some base frequency, so i can't find common `tau`.  Using types with greater precission (double, long double) is not allowed.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Can you use third-party libraries?

Comment: I am not aware of any law that makes it illegal to use more than one `tau`. Precalculate your `tau` for each `w[i]`, store it in a 2nd array, and then use the same basic algorithm, except that you have a `tau` for each `w`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if it can solve the problem, then yes. What do you suggest?

Comment: Set `tau = 2*M_PI/w_min` where `w_min` is the minimum frequency and do the same as in Sample2. Edit: this does not work, please ignore

Comment: @GeorgeGerganov That doesn't work. There probably is some value that works, but Sam's solution seems more robust.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, This is a possible solution! I don't like just that i need an array of  `t`

Comment: Another trick that I used in similar cases: every N samples, recalculate a kind of  `phase += N*dt*w (modulo 2Pi)` to limit accumulation of rounding errors

Comment: There are a few libraries for arbitrary or multiple precision arithmetic. For example [this one](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: You can create an object `sine_generation` with `t` and `w` inside and then a `std::vector` of such objects

Comment: (a) To start, use `double` and `sin` instead of `float` and `sinf`. Possibly `long double` and `sinl` if your C++ implementation has extended precision for those. (b) What do you consider “large” for `t`? What are `modNum` and `runned`; when do the loops stop? (c) How precisely have `w` and `dt` been calculated; what are their error bounds? (d) What is the output of this code? The samples do not do anything with `v`, so computing the sine seems useless. The only state change is `t` is incremented by `dt` some number of times, a number unknown to us since the loop termination is unclear.

Comment: Given the lack of information in the current code samples, you should prepare a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you want to compute.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, (b) dt/t < 10^-8, so the float bit is not enough for the operation t+=dt. `runned` - flag indicating that the program is running. w and dt should be of float type

Comment: @EricPostpischil What kind of information is missing?

Comment: @DmytroDadyka: What is missing is what is being computed. The code shown has `float v = sinf(w * t);`. This `v` is never printed or used in any other expression, and it ceases to exist at the end of each loop iteration. So `sinf(w * t)` is not a part of any output of a program containing these code samples; you might as well delete it. I suspect either **each** `sinf(w * t)` is a separate output (which you have not shown) or you want the **sum** of the `sinf(w * t)` (and have not shown that). But we do not know; it is not stated. The information is missing.

Comment: The bare sum would not make sense, though. If `dt` is any rational number, then dt/(2π) is irrational, and `w*t` would crawl repeatedly around the circle (if computed with exact mathematics). Then the sum of `sin(w*t)` would never converge; after any finite number of iterations, there would always remain an infinite number of values that are not generally diminishing in magnitude to be added in. A sum could make sense of `sin(w*t)` were multiplied by some decreasing amplitude, as that could let the series converge.

Comment: @EricPostpischil. You can assume that `v` value is used for some computations after generating. In the most general form `float v = getSignal(t);   f(v) ;` where f - some function (in a real problem, this is a model of some nonlinear active medium)

Comment: dt/t < 10^-8 tells us where you encounter problems. It does not tell us how large you need t to be. E.g., perhaps we could give you some solution that worked until dt/t < 10^-16. Would that solve your problem because you never need t to be that large, or would you need to support more than that? How large can `modNum` ever be?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, No, I do not calculate the sum or integral.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I would like to have a solution without limitations. How in Sample2. I think  `modNum` should be no more than a hundred.

Comment: Every time one encounters `sin (M_PI * [expr])` one would want to check whether the platform also offers (as an extension beyond the C++ standard) a `sinpi()` function, and then code `sinpi ([expr])`. This should increase both accuracy and performance. It does not get around the general issue that a truly infinite signal is not achievable with fixed-precision floating-point arithmetic. As Eric Postpischil points out, the best approach to achieve as wide an interval as possible is the use of the widest available floating-point format.

Comment: A solution “without limitations” is not reasonable. dt/t < 10^-16 occurs only after 10^16 iterations. `sinf` takes 30 cycles or more, so that is 10^16•30 cycles. Running in parallel on a 2 GHz 16-core processor, that’s 10^16*30/(2•10^9•16) seconds, which is 108.5 days. Are you really running this software for that many days to get `t` to that magnitude?

Comment: There are techniques that can be applied here—floating-point practitioners know ways to compute precisely, mathematics might transform the problem to avoid some floating-point computations, or extended precision can give you any desired accuracy at the expense of computing time—but I suggest you simply start by changing to `double`. It is cheap and will certainly improve the accuracy of `t` dramatically for the first few days of run-time at least.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, your estimation is too optimistic. This estimation corresponds to the sinus degeneration to the meander. In fact, noticeable signal gradation will begin to appear much earlier. "techniques that can be applied here—floating-point practitioners" that would be interesting. Can you tell more?

Comment: First, try `double` and `long double`. Also, instead of using `t += dt;`, start a counter `c` at zero and use `c = c+1; t = c*dt;` in the loop. That eliminates the accumulation of rounding errors. If those are insufficient, then please edit the following into the question: What is the domain of `dt` (what are low and high bounds on its value)? What is the domain of `w`? How accurately has `dt` been calculated (how much error may be in the calculated value)? How accurately has `w` been calculated? How accurately does sine(w•t) need to be calculated?…

Comment: … How accurately does the sum of sine(w[i]•x) need to be calculated? Edit the question to be completely crystal clear about what the actual final results are—is sine(w•t) a final result or is it just one component that goes into sine(w[i]•t)? The fact you are asking this question suggests you have gotten unacceptable results. How do you know they are unacceptable—did you compare to some reference computation? What? Show at least one complete example with fully displayed values for w, dt, the computed sine(w•t) for one or more values of t, and the ideally desired sine(w•t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose an arbitrary `tau` and store the phase reminders for each mod when subtracting it from `t` (as @Damien suggested in the comments).

Also, representing the time as `t = dt * it` where `it` is an integer can improve numerical stability (i think).

Maybe something like this:

```
int ndt = 1000;       // accumulate phase every 1000 steps for example
float tau = dt * ndt;

std::vector<float> phases(modNum, 0.0f);

int it = 0;
float t = 0.0f;
while (runned)
{
   t = dt * it;

   float v = 0.0f;
   for (int i = 0; i < modNum; i++)
   {
       v += sinf(w[i] * t + phases[i]);
   }

   if (++it >= ndt)
   {
       it = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < modNum; ++i)
       {
           phases[i] = fmod(w[i] * tau + phases[i], 2 * M_PI);
       }
   }
}
```